# Storing and retrieving downloaded files

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I have created local folder for downloading files using followling code

```cs
StorageFile destinationFile;
StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;

var dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("AppDownloads",
                CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
destinationFile = await dataFolder.CreateFileAsync(destination,
            CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);
```

Now i need to access all downloaded files from the sub folder created.

I have tried using:

```cs
StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
IStorageFolder dataFolder1 = await local.GetFolderAsync("AppDownloads");

IEnumerable<IStorageFile> files = await local.GetFilesAsync();
```

But this is not working.How to get all downloaded files from this folder ?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you say what is not working? Do you get any exception/other problem?

Comment: I think you have created files in AppDownloads' folder and you are trying to get files from the root local folder. Use IEnumerable<IStorageFile> files = await dataFolder1 .GetFilesAsync(); . This is what i guess and need more clarification if it doesn't solve your problem